# Utilize, but don't expose API (AngularJs/NodeJs)

Tags: angularjs, node.js, api

I have an AngularJs application that consumes an API. I made this API with [`StrongLoop`](http://strongloop.com)

What I want:

1. Be able to consume the API via AngularJs Controllers.
2. Not Expose the API endpoints to the user.

Now I was thinking I would somehow be able to do this with Node, where I query a local site URL with AngularJS and have Node process the routing and authentication token, but what stops the user from just using my local URL to get the results?

Comment: Why are you trying to hide it? As @bakkal said you can't get around it being exposed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I want my website to consume the API, but not provide results to the user if they navigate to it themselves

That's the thing, **on a HTTP level, there is no difference between the two.**

Now you may implement an authentication and authorization system in place. Authentication identifies the client/user, and authorization decides whether a given user can perform a given action or not.

To implement the above, please refer to StrongLoop's [Authentication, authorization, and permissions](https://docs.strongloop.com/display/public/LB/Authentication%2C+authorization%2C+and+permissions)

### Public APIs

If the API accessible to a AngularJS controller (a web client), just assume that it is accessible by the user by "putting the API URL in the browser". There's no way around this, both are valid clients to your API.

If you need to manage permissions, don't rely on the client side to prevent the user from doing it, but rely on the server side.

Permissions on the client side are just for good UX (User Experience, e.g. hide buttons to actions the user isn't allowed to perform).

The API itself doesn't trust any client.

### Internal APIs

Once you have secured your public APIs, you may have internal APIs that only listen to requests from your node.js app to provide a specific service e.g.

```
public clients (ng-app, web browser) ---> public API (node.js) ----> internal API
```

Here you may have the internal API completely trust requests coming your node.js app, because the public API already deals with permissions and only calls the internal API with safe operations.

Comment: I understand this. That is essentially why I am asking for a direction to look  toward, with regard to setting up the server for authorization. I want my website to consume the API, but not provide results to the user if they navigate to it themselves.

Comment: Thank you very much for taking the time to respond and your thorough explanation of the situation. I appreciate your help immensely.

Comment: @DevinStokes Yup, included a link, you'll first want to setup authentication, so you know who's logging in, then setup authorization

Comment: No problem at all glad I could be of help!

Answer (score 0):

I think we need a bit more information on what exactly you're trying to restrict access to.

If you just want to limit the data exposed at the API to what's needed in the application the [MVVM pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93viewmodel) might be a good candidate (I'm not familiar enough with StrongLoop to know if that's an option.)

Otherwise if you need to strictly restrict access to the StrongLoop API so only your server can access it, the [Repository Pattern](http://shawnmc.cool/the-repository-pattern) would be a good candidate for this.